# How can I force a TabItem to initialize content on load?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, tabcontrol, cefsharp

*[disclaimer: I am new to Visual Basic.]*

In a WPF, I have a TabControl containing 2 TabItems:

The first TabItem contains a bunch of URLs.

The second TabItem consists of a DockPanel that contains a cefSharp webView (chromium embedded for .net)

When I click on a url in tab1 it loads a page in the browser contained in tab2... **But, it only works if I have initialized the browser first by clicking on tab2.**

After doing some searching, it looks like vb.net doesn't initialize the content in a TabItem until it becomes visible. (right?)

So, my question is, how can I force a non-selected tab to initialize its content on load, in the background? (ie. so I don't have to click on the tab or switch to it first)

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is the relevant code:

The relevant XAML consists of a single DockPanel named "mainBox"

```
<DockPanel Name="mainBox" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#afe0ff" />
```

And here is my "code behind" vb script:

```
Class MainWindow : Implements ILifeSpanHandler, IRequestHandler

    Shared web_view1 As CefSharp.Wpf.WebView
    Shared web_view2 As CefSharp.Wpf.WebView

    Public Sub init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    'This is in a DockPanel created on the xaml named mainBox

        ' set up tabControl:
        Dim browserTabs As New TabControl()
        browserTabs.BorderThickness = Nothing

        Dim tab1 As New TabItem()
        tab1.Header = "My Tab"

        Dim tab2 As New TabItem()
        tab2.Header = "Browser"

        Dim tab1Content As New DockPanel()
        Dim tab2Content As New DockPanel()

        tab1.Content = tab1Content
        tab2.Content = tab2Content

        browserTabs.Items.Add(tab1)
        browserTabs.Items.Add(tab2)

        mainBox.Children.Add(browserTabs)

        ' set up browsers:
        Dim settings As New CefSharp.Settings()
        settings.PackLoadingDisabled = True

        If CEF.Initialize(settings) Then

            web_view1 = New CefSharp.Wpf.WebView()
            web_view1.Name = "myTabPage"
            web_view1.Address = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

            web_view2 = New CefSharp.Wpf.WebView()
            web_view2.Name = "browserPage"
            web_view2.Address = "https://www.google.com"
            web_view2.LifeSpanHandler = Me
            web_view2.RequestHandler = Me

            AddHandler web_view2.PropertyChanged, AddressOf web2PropChanged

            tab1Content.Children.Add(web_view1)
            tab2Content.Children.Add(web_view2)

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

So, in its default state, tab1 is showing at start up -- the browser on tab2 (web_view2) won't initialize until I click its tab or change to its tab via script.  Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: post your cs and xaml (RELEVENT cs and xaml ) , of your tab control and the content you wan't to init (that means the class which is given as content to the tabitem .

Comment: @eran otzap, thanks for taking the time to look this over -- I edited my question with the relevant code.

Comment: There is nice (but still hacky) solution right in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337976/wpf-tabcontrol-load-all-tabs-at-window-load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't use Windows Forms' `TabPage` but perhaps this might still help

> As we know, [Controls contained in a TabPage are not created until the
>   tab page is shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx), and any data bindings in these controls are not
>   activated until the tab page is shown. This is by design and you can
>   call `TabPage.Show()` method one by one as a workaround.

[via MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d194ec3b-0b28-45fe-896e-131a2da6f087/how-to-force-all-controls-on-all-tab-pages-of-a-tab-control-to-loadcreatehandle-at-once?forum=winforms#2a40b911-06fa-441a-836b-15f6aceba6fe)

Also, based on the above idea, have you tried the following.

```
tab2.isEnabled = True
tab1.isEnabled = True
```

Or:

```
tab2.Visibility = True
tab1.Visibility = True
```

Also, the [BeginInit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.begininit(v=vs.110).aspx) might help in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It would be nice if the controls not being activated "by design" was based on a bool.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but found it initializes if I use the name of the tabpage and show (tabName1.show()) on the form load code for each page ending with the one I want displayed:

```
tabPage2.show()
tabPage3.show()
tabPage4.show()
tabPage5.show()
tabPage1.show()
```

It ripples thru and you never see the pages changing but it works.  The other suggestions didn't work for me in Visual Studio 2010.