# How can I force the content load off all the TabItems of my TabControl in WPF? (using Caliburn.micro)

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have a collection of Screens loaded into a tab control using Caliburn.Micro.

My problem is : Tab content is not loaded until I click on the tab to show it. I've already tried to change the selected index one by one, activate all items and etc but nothing works!

Does anyone know how could I solve this? I'm running out of ideas and hair. Thx!

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="App.Views.ShellView"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
                  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="1"
                  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                  WindowState="Maximized"
                  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="Items" >
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive
{
    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);

        int x = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            MyTabViewModel myTabVm = new MyTabViewModel(x.ToString());
            Items.Add(myTabVm);
        }
    }
}
```

OnViewLoaded fires only when I click on the tab :(

```
public class MyTabViewModel : Screen
{
    public MyTabViewModel(string displayName)
    {
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
        this.ViewAttached += SistemaClaroViewModel_ViewAttached;
    }

    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        GetBrowser().Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com.br/"));
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    }

    public WebBrowser GetBrowser()
    {
        return ((MyTabView)this.GetView()).Browser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852204/how-can-i-force-a-tabitem-to-initialize-content-on-load.
Try to can call `TabPage.Show()` method one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by duplicating my views on my window and making them invisible.
I think its an awful solution, but's all I've got. :/
If someone ends up here with any new suggestions, i'm all ears.

```
<!-- My visible tab control-->
<TabControl Name="Items"
                Grid.Row="0"
                SelectedValue="{Binding ActiveItem}" />

<!-- Duplicated, invisible, tab control's views (Only to force immediate loading -->
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          Visibility="Hidden">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing jumps out at me. Shouldn't the `ShellViewModel` be using the `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive` base. Only one tab can be active at a time? You also need to bind the `Activeitem` onto the tab control. `ActiveItem` is a property of the `OneActive` base class.

Caliburn Micro have a sample utilising a tab control [here](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.SimpleMDI).

Comment: Hi @Jack Hughes! Thank you very much for your answer :)

I was using the OneActive conductor before. I've changed it to "AllActive" just for a test. I've tried your suggestion, going back to OneActive and binding the ActiveItem to my Tab Control.

Unfortunately, I still can't force the content load of all the tab items. Only one tab fires the ViewLoaded event.

Just to Contextualize, I need to have the components inside all my tabs loaded as soon as the application starts, because I have to perform a series of automatons into web-browser's that each tab contains.